# Android bluetooth repeated connections programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-studio

I'm trying to get two android phones to connect via bluetooth. I'm following the instructions here from the android online howto's, and I'm following pretty closely.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I can get bluetooth to connect once, but I have to restart the android device or the app itself in order to get it to connect a second time. This is not a problem during development because with each edit of the code the android studio program re-loads the app. It starts it and restarts it, so that during testing I can connect over and over. During actual use I have to restart the android phone or go to the applications manager option under settings and physically stop that app.

From the code below I can connect if I call these lines:

```
generateDefaultAdapter();
startDiscovery();
startThreadAccept();
startThreadConnect();
```

How do I get it so that the bluetooth connection can be initiated over and over again? I see the message 'unable to connect' from the inner class 'ConnectThread' and an IO error from a 'printStackTrace()' from that part of the code. The second time I try, I seem to be able to call the method 'stopConnection()' and then the lines above (starting with 'generateDefaultAdapter()') but I find I cannot connect.

```
package org.test;

//some import statements here...

public class Bluetooth {

    public boolean mDebug = true;
    public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    public UUID mUUID  = UUID.fromString(BLUETOOTH_UUID);
    public Thread mAcceptThread;
    public Thread mConnectThread;

    public ConnectedThread mManageConnectionAccept;
    public ConnectedThread mManageConnectionConnect;


    public APDuellingBluetooth() {

    }


    public void generateDefaultAdapter() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            (mDialogDuel.getActivity()).startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, INTENT_ACTIVITY_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        }
    }


    public void cancelDiscovery() { if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();}
    public void startDiscovery() { mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();}
    public BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothAdapter() {return mBluetoothAdapter;}


    public void stopConnection () {

        try {
            if (mAcceptThread != null) {

                mAcceptThread.interrupt();
                //mAcceptThread.join();
                mAcceptThread = null;
            }

            if (mConnectThread != null) {

                mConnectThread.interrupt();
                //mConnectThread.join();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            if (mManageConnectionConnect != null) {
                mManageConnectionConnect.cancel();
                mManageConnectionConnect.interrupt();
                mManageConnectionConnect = null;
            }

            if (mManageConnectionAccept != null) {
                mManageConnectionAccept.cancel();
                mManageConnectionAccept.interrupt();
                mManageConnectionAccept = null;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    public void startThreadAccept () {

        if (mAcceptThread != null && !mAcceptThread.isInterrupted()) {
            if (mDebug) System.out.println("server already open");
            //return;
            mAcceptThread.interrupt();
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();

        }
        else {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        }
        if (mAcceptThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW ){
                //mAcceptThread.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }



    public void startThreadConnect () {

        BluetoothDevice mDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mChosen.getAddress());
        //if (mDebug) System.out.println(mDevice.getAddress() + " -- " + mChosen.getAddress() );

        if (mConnectThread != null && !mConnectThread.isInterrupted()) {
            if (mDebug) System.out.println("client already open");
            //return;
            mConnectThread.interrupt();
            mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
        }
        else {
            mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
        }


        if (mConnectThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW){// ||
                //mConnectThread.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
            mConnectThread.start();
        }
    }



    public void manageConnectedSocketAccept(BluetoothSocket socket) {


        String mTemp = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
        if (mDebug) {
            System.out.println("socket accept from " + mTemp);
            System.out.println("info accept " + socket.getRemoteDevice().toString());
        }
        if (mManageConnectionAccept != null && !mManageConnectionAccept.isInterrupted()) {
            //mManageConnectionAccept.cancel();
            //mManageConnectionAccept.interrupt();
            if (mAcceptThread == null) System.out.println(" bad thread accept");
        }
        else {
            mManageConnectionAccept = new ConnectedThread(socket, "accept");
        }

        if (mManageConnectionAccept.getState() == Thread.State.NEW ){//||
                //mManageConnectionAccept.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
            mManageConnectionAccept.start();
        }

    }

    public void manageConnectedSocketConnect(BluetoothSocket socket) {


        String mTemp = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
        if (mDebug) {
            System.out.println("socket connect from " + mTemp);
            System.out.println("info connect " + socket.getRemoteDevice().toString());

        }

        if (mManageConnectionConnect != null && !mManageConnectionConnect.isInterrupted()) {
            //mManageConnectionConnect.cancel();
            //mManageConnectionConnect.interrupt();
            if (mConnectThread == null) System.out.print(" bad thread connect ");
        }
        else {
            mManageConnectionConnect = new ConnectedThread(socket, "connect");
        }
        if (mManageConnectionConnect.getState() == Thread.State.NEW){// ||
                //mManageConnectionConnect.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
            mManageConnectionConnect.start();
        }
    }




    public void decodeInput (String mIn, ConnectedThread mSource) {
        // do something with info that is returned to me...

    }

    public void encodeOutput (String mMac1, String mMac2, int mLR1, int mLR2) {


        String mTemp = composeOutputString ( mServer, mMac1,mMac2, mLR1, mLR2);


        if (mManageConnectionConnect != null && mManageConnectionConnect.isConnected()) {
            mManageConnectionConnect.write(mTemp.getBytes());
            mManageConnectionConnect.flush();

        }
        if (mManageConnectionAccept != null && mManageConnectionAccept.isConnected()) {
            mManageConnectionAccept.write(mTemp.getBytes());
            mManageConnectionAccept.flush();
        }

        mTemp = composeOutputString ( mClient, mMac1,mMac2, mLR1, mLR2);


        if (mManageConnectionConnect != null && mManageConnectionConnect.isConnected()) {
            mManageConnectionConnect.write(mTemp.getBytes());
            mManageConnectionConnect.flush();
        }
        if (mManageConnectionAccept != null && mManageConnectionAccept.isConnected()) {
            mManageConnectionAccept.write(mTemp.getBytes());
            mManageConnectionAccept.flush();
        }
    }

    public String composeOutputString (SocketConnectData mData, String mMac1, String mMac2, int mLR1, int mLR2) {

        // make a string here with the data I want to send...
        String mTemp = new String();
        return mTemp;
    }



    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private boolean mLoop = true;

        public AcceptThread() {


            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            mLoop = true;

            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mServiceNameReceive, mUUID );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("rfcomm problem ");
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (mLoop) {
                try {
                    if (mmServerSocket != null) {
                        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (mDebug) System.out.println("rfcomm accept problem");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null && ! isConnectionOpen() ) {
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    manageConnectedSocketAccept(socket);
                    try {
                        mmServerSocket.close();

                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {}
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mLoop = false;
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        //private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {


            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            try {

                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);


                if (mDebug) System.out.println("connect -- rf socket to service record " + tmp);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("exception -- rf socket to service record problem " + tmp);

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception

                mmSocket.connect();

            }
            //catch (InterruptedException e ) {System.out.println("interrupted exception");}

            catch (IOException e) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                if (mDebug) System.out.println("unable to connect ");

                e.printStackTrace(); //   <---- I see output from this spot!!



                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    System.out.println("unable to close connection ");
                }

                return;
            }


            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            if (mmSocket.isConnected() && ! isConnectionOpen()) {
                manageConnectedSocketConnect(mmSocket);
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public boolean isConnected() {
            return mmSocket.isConnected();
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        public String mTypeName = "";

        private boolean mLoop = true;

        public StringWriter writer;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String type) {
            mTypeName = type;
            mLoop = true;

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

            try {


                writer = new StringWriter();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // 

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            String [] mLines ;



            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (mLoop) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    if (bytes == -1 || bytes == 0) {
                        if (mDebug) System.out.println("zero read");
                        return;
                    }

                    writer.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytes));

                    mLines = writer.toString().split("!");

                    if (mDebug) System.out.println( "lines " +mLines.length);

                    for (int i = 0; i < mLines.length; i ++ ) {


                        if (true) {
                            if (mDebug) System.out.println("  " + mLines[i]);
                            decodeInput (mLines[i], this);


                        }

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (mDebug) System.out.println("read buffer problem");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {

                mmOutStream.write(bytes);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (mDebug) System.out.println("bad write");
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mLoop = false;
                mmSocket.close();
                mmOutStream.close();
                mmInStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public boolean isConnected() {
            boolean mIsOpen = false;
            try {
                mIsOpen = mmSocket.isConnected() ;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return mIsOpen;
        }

        public void flush() {
            try {
                mmOutStream.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: this is the error msg:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err﹕ at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:553)
W/System.err﹕ at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:530)
W/System.err﹕ at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:357)
W/System.err﹕ at org.davidliebman.test.Bluetooth$ConnectThread.run(Bluetooth.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Instead of restarting the app. Turn off the Bluetooth on the Android device and turn it back on after a 5-sec delay. If you could make the connection successfully, it typically a sign that you did not close the connection and socket completely. Log your code. Make sure the closing socket routine is smoothly executed. Check if the `IOException` you have in your `cancel` method of your `ConnectedThread` is not catching any exception:

```
    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            // ADD LOG
            mLoop = false;
            mmSocket.close();
            mmOutStream.close();
            mmInStream.close();
            // ADD LOG
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            // ADD LOG}
    }
```

Comment: Toggling bluetooth does allow the app to run a second time. I am trying to add log statements to the `cancel()` method.

Comment: It seems that the cancel() method is never called. When I add log statements to that part of the code I never see them. I don't know what to do about that. I even tried to add a button to my UI that called finish(). My thought was that I could manually restart the whole app more easily with a button that called 'finish()'. Unfortunately it didn't work. The app has to be restarted anyway from the application manager of the system program, even after executing finish() successfully.

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid restrating the app. All you need to do is to properly back track why the cancel method is not called. I can see you have a stopConnection() method which calls the cancel method. However, what I am not sure about is which thread is your connection on. Maybe try adding the cancel() method to mConnectThread, and mAcceptThread in stopConnection() .

Comment: I was looking at this question but nothing I tried from that page helped my situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022001/android-bluetooth-connection-fails-after-489-successful-connections